# Looking for a specific sermon about Barnabas

Tags: acts, sermon, willow-creek

I remember hearing a sermon<sup>1</sup> in the last few years (so probably after 2010). I think it was a series of three about Josephs in the Bible (hence one sermon per Joseph). The first was about Joseph, son of Jacob; the second was about Joseph, husband of Mary.

I am looking for the third, about Barnabas (referring to his [real name](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+4:36)). I think it was by [Bill Hybels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Hybels) (and probably all three were by the same person) but no amount of Googling on my part can find it.

In it I think he mentions three specific stories from Acts about Barnabas:

- [his selling a field](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+4%3A36-37)
- [his bringing Saul to the believers in Jerusalem](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+9%3A27)
- [his choosing to go on missions with John Mark](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+15%3A36-41)

The latter story was particularly interesting because John Mark later went on ([according to church tradition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Mark)) to meet up with Peter and write the Gospel of Mark. Hence, the speaker said, humanly speaking had Barnabas not encouraged John Mark we would have missed Mark's Gospel (and possibly others).

Hence the focus of the sermon was the power of encouragement.

I'm pretty sure I heard it and did not see it, so it is possibly a podcast. Or perhaps it is from a CD, since it does not seem to be online.

Does anyone know where I have heard this?

<sub>1 There is a possibility that it was not a sermon but a book, but I'm pretty sure I heard it as a sermon.</sub>

Comment: It might be locked on sermonshare.net, which would explain why google hasn't helped. http://barnabasproject.sermonshare.net/

Comment: @LCIII - I don't think I saw it there but I cannot access that link.

Comment: I wonder if exploring why *exactly* you think it was Billy Hybels would help track it down. Is it because you attend(ed) his church? Is he one of a handful of big-name pastors you listen to from time to time? (If so, what are the others?)

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - the latter. I've never attended Willow Creek but have listened to hundreds of their talks. As for other "big name" pastors, none really.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Willow Chicago had [something regarding Barnabas in February 2012](http://www.willowcreek.org/chicago/156-about/1688-discipleship-community1). Could that have been it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

These are probably not what you are looking for, and although John Piper is a Baptist and I'm a Catholic. I still enjoy listening to his sermons, here are a few on [Barnabas](http://www.desiringgod.org/sermons/by-series/barnabas-a-maker-of-leaders) that you might like anyways. Good luck finding your missing sermons.

Answer (score 0):

There is one [here](http://www.keepbelieving.com/sermon/1990-06-03-The-Barnabas-Factor/) which seems to contain the ingredients you are talking about. However, it is not a part of a series on Joseph, but on spiritual gifts. This particular one looks at the gift of encouragement.